# $\lim_{r\to 0}\operatorname{vol}f(B(a;r)) = 0$ whenever $f'(a)$ is not an isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

I've already asked before this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117136/lim-r-to-0-frac-operatornamevolfbar-operatornamevolbar-det/2117147?noredirect=1#comment4354201_2117147). Now I would like to prove the general case, i.e., I want to prove the equality when the $f'(a)$ is not an isomorphism. To sum up I want to prove this:

> Let $U\subset \mathbb R^m$ be an open set and $f:U\to \mathbb R^m$ a function of class $C^1$. Suppose there is  $a\in U$ such that $f'(a):\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$ is  **not** an isomorphism. Show
>
> $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{vol}f(B(a;r))}{\operatorname{vol}B(a;r)} = 0$$

**My attempt 1**

Using the inverse function theorem $f$ is not a local diffeomorphism since $f'(a)$ is not an isomorphism. (Is $f(B(a,r))$ a manifold?) if so, $f(B(a,r))$ has dimension strictly less than $m$, then it has measure zero and it must have empty interior. So we have $\operatorname{vol} f(B(a,r))=0$.

Am I on the right way?

**Attempt 2**

Another way is to follow the suggestion of John B. in the comments of his answer of my previous question:

*"You can write $|\det f′(y)|\lt \epsilon$ and so you can estimate from above easily. From below since the volume is nonnegative we do have $\lim_{r\to 0}≥0$. The matter is instead that since $f′(a)$ is not an isomorphism one cannot use the change of variables formula... but the volume is still at most the integral on the right-hand side."* John B.

In this case I couldn't use the fact $f'(a)\neq 0$ to prove the estimation he said in the first line.

Comment: Would really appreciate an answer to this. For the particular 2 cases: (1) $f$ is linear;  (2) $f'(a) = 0$, it's not hard to prove it. If f is linear and $det f'(a) = 0$, then $det f = 0$, which means $f(R^n)$ has empty interior (being a proper vector subspace of $R^n$), and then $f(B[a; r])$ has volume 0 (because $f(B[a; r]) \subset f(R^n)$). If $f'(a) = 0$, you can use the mean value inequality and find $r_0$ such that $0 < r < r_0$ implies in $f(B[a; r]) \subset B[f(a); \epsilon r]$ ($\epsilon$ given), which means $Vol f(B[a; r]) \le Vol B[f(a); \epsilon r] = {\epsilon}^nVol B[a, r]$

Comment: Found this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2805967/292812